# how to i loop through array using jolt specification

Tags: arrays, json, apache-nifi, jolt

i have the following **input** JSON :

```json
{
  "c2": [
    "142.11.242.31:443",
    "192.119.110.73:443"
  ]
}
```

**desired output** :

```json
{
  "iocs": [
    {
      "ioc": {
        "ioc_type": "sha256",
        "value": "test value"
      },
      "metadata": {
        "meta": {
          "tags": [
            "tag1",
            "tag2",
            "tag3"
          ]
        },
        "source": "test",
        "datetime_observed": "test"
      }
    },
    {
      "ioc": {
        "ioc_type": "ip",
        "value": "142.11.242.31:443"
      },
      "metadata": {
        "meta": {
          "tags": [
            "tag1",
            "tag2",
            "tag3"
          ]
        },
        "source": "test",
        "datetime_observed": "test"
      }
    },
    {
      "ioc": {
        "ioc_type": "ip",
        "value": "192.119.110.73:443"
      },
      "metadata": {
        "meta": {
          "tags": [
            "tag1",
            "tag2",
            "tag3"
          ]
        },
        "source": "test",
        "datetime_observed": "test"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

the first part of the transformation i was able to address it. i am trying to figure out how to loop through the c2 list and transform in a way that i can create individual json objects with its own attributes.

see below the current **spec** :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "ioc_data": {
        "iocs": [
          {
            "ioc": {
              "ioc_type": "sha256",
              "value": "test value"
            },
            "metadata": {
              "meta": {
                "tags": [
                  "tag1",
                  "tag2",
                  "tag3"
                ]
              },
              "source": "test",
              "datetime_observed": "date"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "c2": "c2",
      "ioc_data": {
        "*": "&"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Thank you and look forward to the guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Principally **`"@"`** versus **`"value"`** match is needed, the rest is hardcoding, of one which might be handled through a default spec as a whole object as you already did, and the other parts by using **`#`** wildcards with the shift transformation such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "iocs": {
        "ioc": {
          "ioc_type": "sha256",
          "value": "test value"
        },
        "metadata": {
          "meta": {
            "tags": [
                  "tag1",
                  "tag2",
                  "tag3"
                ]
          },
          "source": "test",
          "datetime_observed": "date"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "c2": {
        "*": { // indexes of the "c2" array 
          "#ip": "iocs[&1].ioc.ioc_type",
          "@": "iocs[&1].ioc.value",
          "#tag1|#tag2|#tag3": "iocs[&1].metadata.meta.tags",
          "#test": ["iocs[&1].metadata.source", "iocs[&1].metadata.datetime_observed"]
        }
      },
      "*": "&" // keeping the default object through use of this
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]